# Python get/pipe/redirect inputs typed into stdin

Tags: python, pipe, stdin

I need to write a function that takes another function as a parameter. The parameter function **is a black box** and I don't have control over it. It calls the `input` function an unspecified number of times. I want to call the parameter function inside my function, then somehow get all user inputs (maybe as a multiline string?), and then return it in my function. Is there any way that I can record all the strings typed into stdin after running the parameter function?

```py
def func():
    input("What is your name? ")
    input("How old are you? ")
    input("What's your favourite animal? ")

def capture_input(func_to_run):
    func_to_run()
    return ...  # somehow return all the previous writes to stdin here
```

Example run in the shell

```
>>> capture_input(func)
What is your name? Mike
How old are you? 100
What's your favourite animal? Dog
"Mike\n100\nDog" # <- This is what the function should return
```

Comment: You could replace the built-in `input()` function with another one that calls the original version, and stores the result somewhere before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you want to do correctly. Store the inputs in a variable, then return them as a tuple. Then return your function inside capture_input.

```
def func():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    age = input("How old are you? ")
    animal = input("What's your favourite animal? ")
    return name, age, animal

def capture_input(func_to_run):
    return func_to_run()
```

Comment: `func` here can ask for more inputs though. Note that `func` is not this specific function. It can be any function that calls the input function.

Comment: Yeah, it would still work if func asked for more inputs. Just make sure it returns it then return the call to func_to_run() and everything will get passed down.

Comment: I don't have the implementation of func though. `func` in this case is a black box. I just run it and capture all the input.

Comment: The function that I want to implement is capture_input, not func.

Comment: OK and the input() values aren't returned?

Comment: Nope. As I said I don’t have control over that

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible.